# Accessing OBJ without altering it

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm looking at how to access a object without altering it into an array as seen in other answers. For example, I have a object starting like the following, where I want to access the `_attributes` array.

I'm new to objects, forgive me.

```
    User Object
    (
        [_profile:protected] => 
        [created_at] => 2015-03-25 05:09:16
        [created_by] => 
        [updated_at] => 2015-03-25 05:09:16
        [updated_by] => 
        [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 
        [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [guid] => 09da4555-f61e-4cab-a552-f3ef3d0e23f8
                [wall_id] => 1
                [group_id] => 1
                [status] => 1
                [super_admin] => 1
```

Comment: Are you using Yii framework?

Comment: Yes, I am. I figured it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I'd have to access the object like `$var->attributes->id` or `$var->displayName` etc.